# first 1 in a bitmask using log2

Tags: computer-science, logarithms, binary

I am trying to get the last 1 in a bitmask. More mathematically speaking, I have a number k, that can be written in its binary form as a sequence of 1 and 0. I want the "weight" or "index" of the last 1 in that number (from the right).

As an example, for the number  0b 10 0100 (36 in decimal), I want to get 3 (because the rightmost 1 is on 3rd position from the right)

I can find the first 1 easily (in my case 6), as the size of the number, or its base-2 log (rounded down +1), but what about the last one?

For information, I will use this in a dirty trick in MS Excel, described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065432/excel-find-last-value-in-an-array/11246728#11246728

Comment: A straightforward but not particularly nice solution is to divide repeatedly by $2$ until you get a non-integer; the number of divisions is the desired result.

Comment: If you have a reasonably conventional set of bitwise operators available, you can isolate the last bit using `x AND NOT (x-1)`. But you might need to use logarithms to find its position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ is your original number, `(~x + 1) & x` will have only one bit set, the same as the least significant set bit of $x$.  For example, if $x$ is `10101000`, then `(~x + 1) & x` = `00001000`.  Perhaps that helps?  You can then use a lookup table, or one of the techniques in [Which bit is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465098/bit-twiddling-which-bit-is-set) to figure out which bit is still set.

You might also look at the references given the [the OEIS entry for this function](http://oeis.org/A091090).

Comment: Of course, in 2's complement arithmetic `(~x + 1)` is simply `-x`.

Comment: Great answer. Still have to port those operators to MS Excel, of course...